# Joint Order Statistics

Tags: probability, statistics

> Say we have the sample $X_{(1)} < X_{(2)} < X_{(3)}$ from the distribution $f_X(x) = 2x$, $0<x<1$.
>
> What is the probability that the minimum and the maximum are between $0.1$ and $0.7$?

My approach,

Let $X = X_{(1)}$ and $Y = Y_{(3)}$. Then $f_{X, Y}(x, y) = 48(xy^5 - 2y^3x^3 + x^5y)$

We want $$\int_{0.1}^{0.7}\int_{0.1}^{0.7}48(xy^5 - 2y^3x^3 + x^5y)dxdy$$

However, this integration becomes very messy. Is there a better alternative?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hint:** Do not focus on the distribution of the order statistics.   Look to the original samples.

The probability that the minimum and maximum of three *independent and identically distributed* random variables are between two numbers, is the probability that *all of them* are between those numbers.

Comment: As in $f_{(1, 2, 3)}(x_{(1)}, x_{(2)}, x_{(3)}) = (3!\cdot2^3)x_{(1)}x_{(2)}x_{(3)},  x_{(1)} < x_{(2)} < x_{(3)}$?

Comment: No. Just calculate the probabilities that each of the samples falls within the range.  Not the order statistics.

Comment: @Retty To reiterate, $$0.1<x_{(1)},x_{(3)}<0.7\iff 0.1<x_1,x_2,x_3<0.7$$